# How can I sell a lot of items?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Yesterday, I was trying to knock off the ? Markers in Skellige. You may know, a lot of them are smuggler caches, so I loot a buttload of armors and swords.

When I'm so full I can't carry more, I go and sell the stuff to an armorer or Smith closeby.

Thing is, I'm now high level and I get expensive items, so last night, I had to run all over the world to find a Smith that had enough coin to take my 60th chestplate of the flaming rose.

Is there somewhere I could go that will always have the money to buy off my armors and swords, or should I just say screw it and dismantle everything I find?

PS Sorry for life story.

Comment: Assuming you could get all that money, what would you do with it? For me, the fun is tracking down those remote places, looking around to see what they're like, looking for any particularly unusual items (journal notes from the people who left their stuff there, one-of-a-kind treasures, etc.), then moving on.

Comment: 1- The place is not checked on the map until you pick up the items, 2- then you have to much stuff in inventory. So you have to sell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I am finding, there is no place that has an infinite amount of coins. No one has mentioned in this [Steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/615085406661817054/) that there is a merchant that has infinite coins (I know a Steam post isn't the best source, buts all I could really find). It looks like the best place to go is Oxenfurt and Novigrad because of the number of merchants there, but even they run out of money. It looks like after 5 days their coins restock.

I found a [Reddit that suggests a trick](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/3b7lm7/tired_of_vendors_running_out_of_money_to_buy_all/?client=ms-android-att-us). I'll attempt to summarize what you have to do:

1. Go to the bottle vendor in Novigrad. He is on the north shoreline.  He sells his bottles for one Crown each.
2. Buy all his bottles. Do this as much as you would like. His stock replenishes instantly after leaving the trade screen so you can continue to do this.
3. Sell all your junk to the bottle merchant once he has enough money.
4. Go to the loanshark near the fast travel sign near Novigrad's south gate. The loanshark has an instantly replenishing supply of Florens he sells for 3 Crowns each (which is apparently the same as a bank).
5. Buy enough Florens to sell him your bottles to make your money back.
6. Go to the bank in Novigrad Square and exchange the Florens for Crowns.

Whether or not this has been patched or they altered the time line of when the stock of each merchant involved works I'm not sure, but it's worth a shot. I'm not sure if it's really worth the time and effort though.

Comment: Sadly, it seems the pawn shop has been patched out. He doesn't have any florens anymore.

But I guess you can buy the bottles and then sell them every where. Selling 1000 bottles is easier than finding the vendor that has the money to buy off your 1000+ G sword.

Comment: @Fredy31 that's a bummer. Well from my research it doesn't seem like there's a way to do what you are looking for.

Comment: its worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Usually I go to any master-crafters or the armourer in Skillege palace to sell my items. They have have around 4k gold each and can replenish with a 5 day's meditation.